# sqlserver sum with minus

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I use sqlserver 2012.
I have a query like this

```
SELECT SUM(TH.CLEAVE_EARN_DAY), SUM(TH.CLEAVE_DAY), 
       SUM(TH.CLEAVE_EARN_DAY) - SUM(TH.CLEAVE_DAY) 
FROM TH_LEAVE_CARD TH
```

The result is 0, 14.5, -15
so -15 is wrong. Must be -14.5

any suggestion ?

Comment: Do you have float columns? If yes check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322778/avg-of-float-inconsistency/33323021#33323021

Comment: This would seem to be a type issue.  My guess is that decimals are being used for one of the columns.

Comment: What is the datatype of the CLEAVE_EARN_DAY and CLEAVE_DAY columns?

Answer (score 3):

This is what you can try

```
SELECT SUM(TH.CLEAVE_EARN_DAY), SUM(TH.CLEAVE_DAY), 
   SUM(TH.CLEAVE_EARN_DAY)*1.0 - SUM(TH.CLEAVE_DAY) 
FROM TH_LEAVE_CARD TH
```

Multiplying with 1.0 will just give you back decimal value and taking away will give you what you asked for

Answer (score 0):

Try converting all arguments to the same datatype and then do calculation:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CAST(TH.CLEAVE_EARN_DAY AS DECIMAL(18,2))),
  SUM(CAST(TH.CLEAVE_DAY AS DECIMAL(18,2))), 
  SUM(CAST(TH.CLEAVE_EARN_DAY AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
    - CAST(TH.CLEAVE_DAY AS DECIMAL(18,2))) AS substraction 
FROM TH_LEAVE_CARD TH
```

Also you can combine:

```
SUM(TH.CLEAVE_EARN_DAY) - SUM(TH.CLEAVE_DAY)
```

to (if both column are `NOT NULL`):

```
SUM(TH.CLEAVE_EARN_DAY - TH.CLEAVE_DAY)
```

or (thanks [`Arvo`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35777/arvo) for pointing this):

```
SUM(ISNULL(TH.CLEAVE_EARN_DAY,0) - ISNULL(TH.CLEAVE_DAY,0))
```

Comment: About `sum(a)-sum(b)` equality to `sum(a-b)` - only when there are no null values.

Comment: @Arvo Good point, of course when we are deal with nullable column we need to use `ISNULL/COALESCE`

Answer (score 0):

To perform mathematical operations on columns:

1. Used columns should be converted into same numeric/decimal data type.
2. To handle null values you may use `ISNULL` function.
   Ex:

   ```
   SELECT SUM(TH.CLEAVE_EARN_DAY), SUM(TH.CLEAVE_DAY), 
      SUM(cast  (TH.CLEAVE_EARN_DAY) as decimal(5,1)) - SUM(cast ( (TH.CLEAVE_DAY) as decimal(5,1))
   FROM TH_LEAVE_CARD
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There is few reason why the result is not as per what you are expecting. In Sql Server any math operation that contains a null would result to null. for example sum(1,2,3,null,4) is equal to null. 1 + null also equal to null.

therefore it would be safer to use isnull function to assign a default value in case the value is null.

for mathematical operation. sql server would do the calculation based on the specified data type. for example int / int = int. therefore the result would be missled. because most of the time int / int = float.

it would be better to change the value to double prior to do any arithmetic operation.

below is the example after include the isnull function as well as cast to float.

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(ISNULL(TH.CLEAVE_EARN_DAY,0) as double)), SUM(cast(ISNULL(TH.CLEAVE_DAY,0) as double)), 
       SUM(cast(ISNULL(TH.CLEAVE_EARN_DAY,0) as double)) - SUM(cast(ISNULL(TH.CLEAVE_DAY,0) as double)) 
FROM TH_LEAVE_CARD TH
```

Comment: kindly add explanation