# Reg: Add SUM of two values vs. Add values and SUM it gives different output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This might be a silly question.  I have a staff `table` which stores staff Information. I need to get the salary for each staff. So I tried below queries

```
SELECT staffid, SUM(ISNULL(amount,0) +ISNULL(bonus,0)) as amount
from payments
group by staffid
```

But I got wrong output. Then I tried as below,

```
SELECT staffid, SUM(ISNULL(amount,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(bonus,0))
from payments
group by staffid
```

This time I got the correct `output`. But I wonder why the difference occurs. Does above two `sum` operations are different? someone please give some idea about this.

Comment: Are you sure that it is SQL Server and not mySQL? **`The isnull function requires 2 argument(s).`**

Comment: yes. sql-server 2012. Sorry I created this query  for demonstration . now i have corrected the query

Comment: Are amount and bonus `FLOAT/REAL`?

Comment: @lad2025  they are money datatype

Comment: @jarlh i dont get your point, I have handled ISNULL in both statements

Comment: what means *'I got wrong output'* ?

Comment: @jarlh I wanted to exlude this case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322778/avg-of-float-inconsistency/33323021#33323021 The datatype matters.

Comment: @bmsqldev, sorry, my bad, multi-tasking error.

Comment: I meant I should get the correct salary amount for each user (amount + bonus). which I didn't  get in first case

Comment: @bmsqldev Please prepare sample data to illustrate your case http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: good idea, I cannot reproduce this bug

Comment: it should be related to rounding. for #1, rounding executes after add up salary & bonus, #2 rounds result after the total amt of 12 months is calculated.