# If I only need 1 or 2 digit accuracy, is float better than decimal type?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I only need 1 or 2 digit after the decimal place accuracy, should I use `float` or still go with `decimal(18,2)`?

The numeric value in question represents salary.

Comment: Salary - use `DECIMAL/NUMERIC/MONEY` which are accurate datatypes or you will ask question like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35885812/mssql-decimal-sum-and-float-sum-difference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between numeric,float and decimal in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056323/difference-between-numeric-float-and-decimal-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `decimal` type or better still, `money` type, which is specially suited for these needs.

You should not use `float` as float is an approximate representation of a decimal value.
See MSDN documentation why we should not use `float` [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912(v=sql.105).aspx)

> The float and real data types are known as approximate data types. The behavior of float and real follows the IEEE 754 specification on approximate numeric data types.
>   Approximate numeric data types do not store the exact values specified for many numbers; they store an extremely close approximation of the value. For many applications, the tiny difference between the specified value and the stored approximation is not noticeable. At times, though, the difference becomes noticeable.
>
> Because of the approximate nature of the float and real data types, **do not use these data types when exact numeric behavior is required, such as in financial applications**, in operations involving rounding, or in equality checks. Instead, use the integer, decimal, money, or smallmoney data types.

Answer (score 1):

The main question in deciding whether you want to use a binary decimal or a decimal decimal is not accuracy, really. It's "how would I expect the calculations to proceed".

The main thing you get from `decimal` is something you can calculate on paper, with fixed-point numbers. E.g.:

```
  13.22
+  7.3
  -----
  20.52
```

It's not really that `decimal` is more precise than a `float` (though it can be that as well, for certain applications). The point is it makes the same mistakes you would make on paper - it's a decimal decimal number, not binary.

Or in another line of thought, your inputs are definitely decimal decimal numbers (typically, in a string or such). So if you use a float, you get decimal -> binary -> calculation -> decimal. Binary to decimal means no loss of information (and finite binary number can be exactly represented in a finite decimal number), but the other way around this isn't true - even something like `0.1` has *no* finite representation in a binary decimal number (just like `1 / 3` has no finite representation in a decimal decimal number, but works fine in say base 6).

Comment: Just wondering: do you know of any performance differences between the two (apart from the tiny advantage of using 4 bytes with float instead of 9 bytes with decimal(18,2) as suggested in the question?

Comment: @Ralph Last time I checked, there was still very little hardware support for  decimal decimal numbers. Narrow fixed point numbers can quite easily by emulated using non-decimal numbers, though I don't know if MS SQL exploits this or not. In the end, the question never really came up - when you need decimal precision, you need decimal precision - float simply isn't going to cut it, no matter how much faster it could possibly be :)