# Redshift division result does not include decimals

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to do something really quite basic to calculate a kind of percentage between two columns in Redshift. However, when I run the query with an example the result is simply zero because the decimals are not being covered.

code:

```
select 1701 / 84936;
```

Output:

[image]

I tried :

```
select cast(1701 / 84936 as numeric (10,10));
```

but the result was `0.0000000000`.

How could I solve this silly thing?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is integer division. Make sure that at least one argument is: `NUMERIC`(accurate data type)/`FLOAT`(caution: it's approximate data type):

> **/   division (integer division truncates the result)**

```
select 1701.0 / 84936;
-- or
SELECT 1.0 * 1701 / 84936;
-- or
SELECT CAST(1701 AS NUMERIC(10,4))/84936;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=de43080be49c1b3da066394849fa2eb6)**

Comment: If you remove the reference to `FLOAT` then I'll upvote ;)  Anyone that asks this question doesn't need directing to the den of vipers that is floating point arithmetic...

Comment: Dude thanks so much I came from SQL school then bunch of things are a bit different here. I knew it it was something silly.

Comment: @MatBailie Yes, you are right that float could be dangerous. For instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322778/avg-of-float-inconsistency

Answer (score 3):

### When mixing data types the order counts

Note that the order of the elements in a math expression counts for the data type of the result.
Let's assume that we intend to calculate the percentage `unit_sales/total_sales` where both columns (or numbers) are integers.

See and try with this code [here](https://onlinegdb.com/ryIsKw-UU).

```sql
-- Some dummy table
drop table if exists sales;
create table sales as 
    select 3 as unit_sales, 9 as total_sales;

-- The calculations
select
    unit_sales/total_sales*100,   --> 0 (integer)
    unit_sales/total_sales*100.0, --> 0.0 (float)
    100.0*unit_sales/total_sales  --> 33.3 (float and expected result)
from sales;
```

The output

```
  0 | 0.0 | 33.33
```

1. The first column is 0 (integer) because of 3/9=0 in an integer division.
2. The second column is 0.0 because SQL first got the integer 0 (3/9), and later, SQL converts it to float in order to perform the multiplication by 100.0.
3. The expected result.
   The non-integer 100.0 at the beginning of the expression force a non-integer calculation.

Comment: This is a much cleaner approach to solving this problem imo