# Why is it that SUM(a + b) != SUM(a) + SUM(b) in Hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I'm running Hive 1.1.0 and see that for two `bigint` columns, `active_users` and `inactive_users`, `SUM(active_users + inactive_users)` < `SUM(active_users) + SUM(inactive_users)`.

Why is that the case, given it should be a simple addition of integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the case when one but not both values are `NULL`.

So, consider:

```
 a     b
 1     1
 2     NULL
 NULL  3
```

Then `sum(a) + sum(b)` is the sum of:  `(1 + 2)` and `(1 + 3)` = 7.  The `NULL` is ignored.

However, `sum(a + b)` is the sum of:

```
 (1 + 1)
 (2 + NULL)
 (NULL + 3)
```

This evaluates to:

```
 2
 NULL
 NULL
```

The `NULL`s are ignored, so the result is 2.

In other words, `SUM()` ignores `NULL` values, but `+` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities:

1) Not handling `NULL` value if columns are nullable

```
SUM(active_users + inactive_users) 
SUM(active_users) + SUM(inactive_users)

-- should be
SUM(COALESCE(active_users,0) + COALESCE(inactive_users,0)) 
SUM(COALESCE(active_users,0)) + SUM(COALESCE(inactive_users,0))
```

2) If column has inexact data type like `FLOAT` round error could accumulate.

More info: [Avg of float inconsistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322778/avg-of-float-inconsistency/33323021#33323021)