# Inconsistent results with float calculations in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, floating-point

I have an ETL process running on SQL Server 2017 on Linux.

The process has some floating point calculations, and I noticed on two different runs of the same process, I got slightly different results.  One run gave me something like 1.23450000...1, and another gave me 1.23459999...  Both are approximations of an exact value of 1.2345.  The difference is on the order of 10e-15 or so.

I know that if I care about two numbers being exactly equal, I shouldn't be using floating point in the first place.  I could accept either result as correct, since both are within some small epsilon of the "correct" answer.

So my real question is more a curiosity about the variation of the approximation itself.  Do I have to assume the binary representation of a floating point result in SQL Server may not be exactly the same every time?  Are there reasons why you could get different results, for example maybe a SUM iterates rows in a different order, or a different query plan yields a different representation?  If this is the case, it would never be safe to assume you can compare floating points for exact equality, even if it's result from current run vs. results from last run.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible that: ["maybe a SUM iterates rows in a different order"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33323021/5070879) and yields different results when summing FLOAT

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Thanks for the pointer.  I found lots of good resources that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SUM` is the likely culprit compared with parallelism / maxdop > 1.

An individual addition operation on floats is deterministic, but additions are not associative, so a `SUM` may not produce consistent results if the rows are processed in a different order.  This other question summarizes it nicely:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/233513/non-deterministic-sum-of-floats